# Byte Buddy Runtime generation for spring boot JPA repository classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, byte-buddy

I am using **Byte Buddy** to generate JPA entities and JPA repository. I am able to generate the JPA entities but not able to proceed in generating corresponding JPA repositories. Following is the code which represent Person entity,

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected Person(){}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person[id=%d]",id,name);
    }
}
```

I am able to generate the above using Bute Buddy as follows,

```
Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Object.class)
    .name("Person")
    .defineField("id", Integer.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
    .defineMethod("getId", Integer.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
    .defineMethod("setId", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).withParameter(Integer.class)
    .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded();
```

Now I would like to generate corresponding Spring boot Jpa reporitories as below,

```
import com.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository <Person, Long> {

}
```

How to create this interface with Generic attribute. Also will this work (using dynamic code generation) to persist Person object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `TypeDescription.Generic.Builder::parameterizedType` to create a generic type:

```
TypeDescription.Generic genericType = TypeDescription.Generic.Builder
   .parameterizedType(JpaRepository.class, type, Long.class)
   .build();
```

You can then supply this generic type to `ByteBuddy::makeInterface`:

```
DynamicType dt = new ByteBuddy()
  .makeInterface(genericType)
  .name("com.model.Person")
  .make();
```

A Byte Buddy generated class cannot be distinguished from one generated by javac, therefore this should work just as expected.

Comment: No offense, but this doesn't answer the second part of the question, "will this work (using dynamic code generation) to persist Person object". How does it work?

Comment: I added a sentence to clarify that it should not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am curious to know how we should do it in a Spring Boot application where beans are managed by the framework in container and there's also dependency injection. Can we really create `@Entity` and `@Repository` classes at runtime? How can we do it without .class files that Spring normally scans for? Or is it that all we can do is to generate .class files at compile time (separate the ByteBuddy code gen source from the Spring project) and deploy them together with the JAR? If that's the case then it's like MapStruct or Lombok. Thank you.

Comment: You can either create them add build time or register beans manually into the application context.