# Register Spring reactive repository using Byte Buddy

Tags: java, spring, byte-buddy

I want to create and register at runtime using **Byte Buddy** a trio of three entities (a class for entity/table, a repository interface and controller class)

```
Class<?> tableClass =
    new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR)
        .name(className)
        .annotateType(getTableAnnotation(tableName))
        .defineField("id", UUID.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
        .annotateField(getIdAnnotation())
        .defineMethod("getId", UUID.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
        .defineMethod("setId", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .withParameter(UUID.class)
        .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty());
        .defineField("name", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
        .defineMethod("getName", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
        .defineMethod("setName", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
        .withParameter(String.class)
        .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
        .make()
        .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();

TypeDescription.Generic repositoryTypeDescription =
    TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
            R2dbcRepository.class, tableClass, UUID.class)

Class<? extends Object> repositoryClass =
    new ByteBuddy()
        .makeInterface(repositoryTypeDescription)
        .name(tableClass.getCanonicalName() + "Repository")
        .make()
        .load(tableClass.getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();
```

I have also a service class that does all bean registration

```
@Service
public class BeanRegisterService {

  @Autowired private BeanFactory beanFactory;
  @Autowired private R2dbcEntityTemplate entityTemplate;

  public <T> void registerBean(String beanName, T bean) {
    ((ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory).registerSingleton(beanName, bean);
  }

  public <T> void registerBeanDefinition(String beanName, Class<T> rootBeanClass) {
    BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefinitionBuilder =
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(rootBeanClass);
    ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
        .registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinitionBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
  }

  public <T> void registerRepositoryBeanDefinition(
      String entityBean, Class<T> repositoryInterface) {
    BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefinitionBuilder =
        BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
            .addConstructorArgValue(repositoryInterface)
            .addPropertyValue("databaseClient", entityTemplate.getDatabaseClient())
            .addPropertyValue("dataAccessStrategy", entityTemplate.getDataAccessStrategy());

    ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory)
        .registerBeanDefinition(
            repositoryInterface.getSimpleName(), beanDefinitionBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
  }
}
```

```
beanService.registerBeanDefinition(tableClass.getSimpleName(), tableClass);
beanService.registerRepositoryBeanDefinition(tableClass.getSimpleName(), repositoryClass);
```

When I try to gain access to the repository bean via `ApplicationContext` I get an error: `MyRepository referenced from a method is not visible from class loader`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.MyRepository referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.ensureVisible(Proxy.java:858) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.validateProxyInterfaces(Proxy.java:681) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:627) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1006) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:126) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
        at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:179) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

The table class has a more dynamic definition than above example and it is not known at build time; so all the classes must be generated at runtime on demand.

What am I missing?

My code is based on answers from:

[Byte Buddy Runtime generation for spring boot JPA repository classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615861/byte-buddy-runtime-generation-for-spring-boot-jpa-repository-classes)

[How to register custom JPA interface using bytebuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71100421/how-to-register-custom-jpa-interface-using-bytebuddy)

**Edit:**

If I load `repositoryClass` with `this.getClass()` it doesn't make it to ProxyBuilder.
It crashes way sooner with ClassNotFound.
Switching ClassLoadingStrategy to persistent does not help either.
On the other hand `tableClass` bean gets loaded without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to inject the class into the targeted class loader rather then creating a new one (which is the default). So instead of:

```
load(getClass().getClassLoader())
```

You'd use:

```
load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECT)
```

For Java 9+, you'd rather use ClassLoadingStrategy.UsingLookup. It has a factory that would work on either JVM version.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you!